# adapter method notifyDataSetChanged not refreshing listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I could use some help with this weird issue.
Upon first load, my listview is blank.
If I click to load the page again, either by exiting to another activity or by refreshing the same activity, my list shows.
Any ideas? Thanks.

My Variables:

```
private static ArrayList<Media_Info> mediaIntroQueueList = new ArrayList<Media_Info>();
private static ArrayList<String> mediaIntroQueueListTitles = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> stringAdapter;
ListView mediaList;
```

OnCreate: where i set my stringAdapter

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meet);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    // LOG
    Log.i("Constants", Constants.userID);

    mediaList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mediaListView);

    stringAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mediaIntroQueueListTitles);
    mediaList.setAdapter(stringAdapter);


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.i("ACTIVITY", "onStart");

    getUserLocation();

    getLocalIntroductions();

}

private void getLocalIntroductions() {

/// a bunch of firebase db calls

                if (mediaLocationKeysWithinRadius.contains(mediaID)) {

                    Log.i("media within radius: ", mediaID);
                    newItems.add(mediaInfoDic);
                    newItemsTitles.add(title);

                    }
                else {
                    Log.i("media not in radius: ", mediaID);
                }
            }

            mediaIntroQueueList = newItems;
            mediaIntroQueueListTitles = newItemsTitles;

            stringAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Do you see the mediaId logged in the first launch? To be honest, i'm surprised you're seeing any items in the list, because as far as i can see, you never add any items to your adapter's data. Also you're code is not complete

Comment: can you format your code and are you sure you call `stringAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` right after you update your dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you assigned a new ArrayList to mediaIntroQueueListTitles. Should use add() directly.

```
private void getLocalIntroductions() {

    /// a bunch of firebase db calls
    // Clear your ArrayLists if you need to
    mediaIntroQueueList.clear();
    mediaIntroQueueListTitles.clear();
    if (mediaLocationKeysWithinRadius.contains(mediaID)) {
        Log.i("media within radius: ", mediaID);
        mediaIntroQueueList.add(mediaInfoDic);
        mediaIntroQueueListTitles.add(title);
    }
    else {
        Log.i("media not in radius: ", mediaID);
    }
    stringAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem in my opinion since the reference that _adapter_ had is now assigned to a new list with elements of its own so `notifyDataSetChanged()` should update the _ListView_ with respect to new list.

Comment: i made these changed and this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar if you assign a new arraylist to the arraylist objects. The adapter loses reference to your list and notifyDataSetChanged() won't work.